# Does this property persists for the derivatives $f^{(k)}, k=1,2,..$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, analyticity

Let $f$ be a real non polynomial analytic function. Suppose that the function $f$ assumes arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small values, i.e., for all $K>0$, there are $a,b$ with $f(a)<−K$ and $f(b)>K$.

My **question** is:

Does this property persists for the derivatives $f^{(k)}, k=1,2,..$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = x + \sin(x)$.